# Infinitely Looping if statement

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

First: I keep running into an infinite loop in the following code. The code is built so that you enter 8 numbers between 1 and 10. It proofs that these numbers are between 1 and 10. Then the second proof is that these 8 numbers added together equal 60. I'm having trouble with the end if else statement. If the total of the numbers is 60 it works fine and gives the print out but if it gets stopped at the if statement it infinitely prints the *"You've entered the wrong total number"* printout as well as an ever increasing total number of points. Am I missing something easy like a parenthesis or something?

Secondly: How can I loop back to the original entering of values if the total is not 60 and start the whole process over?

```
public static void lebronJames() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     //Declare an array to hold 8 intgers values
     int lebronJamesAttributes[] = new int[8];
     int attribute = 0;


     System.out.println("Please allocate your attribute points for Lebron James in the following order. Your point allocations per attribute should be between 1 and 10. You have a total of 60 points to allocate");
     System.out.println("-----------------");
     System.out.println("Close Range" + "\n" + "Mid Range" + "\n" + "Three Point" + "\n" + "Free Throw" + "\n" + "Offensive Rebound" + "\n" + "Defensive Rebound" + "\n" + "Assist" + "\n" + "Steal" + "\n");        

     while (attribute <= 7) {
         int attributeValue = input.nextInt();
         if (attributeValue >= 1 && attributeValue <= 10 ) {
             lebronJamesAttributes[attribute] = attributeValue;
             attribute++;
         } 
         else {
             System.out.println("The attribute value you have selected is out of range. Select again.");
         }  
     }              
            int jamesTotalQuarter = 0;
            while (jamesTotalQuarter != 60){
                for (int jamesTotalQ1 : lebronJamesAttributes){
                     jamesTotalQuarter += jamesTotalQ1;
                }


                if (jamesTotalQuarter != 60) {
                    System.out.println("You have entered the wrong total number of attribute points. Please enter a total of 60 attribute points between the 8 characteristics.");
                    System.out.println("You have allocated a total of " + jamesTotalQuarter + " points.");
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Close Range" + lebronJamesAttributes[0] + "\n" + "Mid Range" + lebronJamesAttributes[1] + "\n" + "Three Point" + lebronJamesAttributes[2] + "\n" + "Free Throw" + lebronJamesAttributes[3] + "\n" + "Offensive Rebound" + lebronJamesAttributes[4] + "\n" + "Defensive Rebound" + lebronJamesAttributes[5] + "\n" + "Assist" + lebronJamesAttributes[6] + "\n" + "Steal" + lebronJamesAttributes[7] + "\n");         
                    System.out.println("You have allocated a total of " + jamesTotalQuarter + " points.");}

                }


                }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop adds `jamesTotalQuarter` based on the elements in the `lebronJamesAttributes` array. Such that you could skip over `60`, leading to an infinite loop. For example if I'm at `jamesTotalQuarter = 55` and the next item in `lebronJamesAttributes` is `10`. You get `65`. And since your adding numbers it will always not be `60`.

Comment: you need to create some recursive functioin to achieve your output

Comment: Spencer Wieczorek should I be rephrasing in some kind of inequality like jamesTotalQuarter > 60 || jamesTotalQuarter < 60 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if the following code solves your problem.  Have not tested it, but it should just work fine now. Get the logic and fix it yourself incase of errors.

```
public static void lebronJames() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
               While(true){ // keeps it in a loop forever and only a "break" statement can stop it

                 //Declare an array to hold 8 intgers values
                 int lebronJamesAttributes[] = new int[8];
                 int attribute = 0;
                 System.out.println("Please allocate your attribute points for Lebron James in the following order. Your point allocations per attribute should be between 1 and 10. You have a total of 60 points to allocate");
                 System.out.println("-----------------");
                 System.out.println("Close Range" + "\n" + "Mid Range" + "\n" + "Three Point" + "\n" + "Free Throw" + "\n" + "Offensive Rebound" + "\n" + "Defensive Rebound" + "\n" + "Assist" + "\n" + "Steal" + "\n");        

                 while (attribute <= 7) {
                     int attributeValue = input.nextInt();
                     if (attributeValue >= 1 && attributeValue <= 10 ) {
                         lebronJamesAttributes[attribute] = attributeValue;
                         attribute++;
                     } 
                     else {
                         System.out.println("The attribute value you have selected is out of range. Select again.");
                     }  
                 }              
                 int jamesTotalQuarter = 0;
                 for (int jamesTotalQ1 : lebronJamesAttributes){
                      jamesTotalQuarter += jamesTotalQ1;
                 }


                 if (jamesTotalQuarter != 60) {
                      System.out.println("You have entered the wrong total number of attribute points. Please enter a total of 60 attribute points between the 8 characteristics.");
                      System.out.println("You have allocated a total of " + jamesTotalQuarter + " points.");
                     continue;     // loop execution starts from the beginning and your program gets fresh inputs.       
    }
                 else {
                                System.out.println("Close Range" + lebronJamesAttributes[0] + "\n" + "Mid Range" + lebronJamesAttributes[1] + "\n" + "Three Point" + lebronJamesAttributes[2] + "\n" + "Free Throw" + lebronJamesAttributes[3] + "\n" + "Offensive Rebound" + lebronJamesAttributes[4] + "\n" + "Defensive Rebound" + lebronJamesAttributes[5] + "\n" + "Assist" + lebronJamesAttributes[6] + "\n" + "Steal" + lebronJamesAttributes[7] + "\n");         
                                System.out.println("You have allocated a total of " + jamesTotalQuarter + " points.");}
                                break; // breaks from the loop on correct input

                            }

                       }

            }
```

Comment: Adding the break does work but the continue leads to another infinite loop.

Comment: @user4343023 You asked "How can I loop back to the original entering of values if the total is not 60 and start the whole process over?" So when the total is not 60, it starts the loop from the beginning and asks the user for input. If that's not what you wanted, could your please explain what are you expecting the program to do when the total is not 60?

Comment: Ashwin Surana when the total is not 60 the program continues to print out "You've entered the wrong total number....." and the total infinitely. What I want it to do when the total != 60 is print the prompt "You have entered the wrong total number of attribute points. Please enter a total of 60 attribute points between the 8 characteristics." and "You have allocated a total of " + jamesTotalQuarter + " points." Then loop back to the beginning of the user entering their values again.

Comment: @user4343023 My program should work as you say. Anyways I have put the scanner line outside the loop. Try now . The continue statement will make the program to get the input once again from the user.